# Unitialized Constant for custom rails class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create an instance of class in a rails model

/app/models/employee.rb

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.import(file)
        preferences = ::MotionlessAgitator::EmployeeAvailability.new
        ...
    end
end
```

except it does exist in:

/app/models/motionlessagitator/employeeavailability.rb

```
module MotionlessAgitator
    class EmployeeAvailability
        def initialize(csv_name = nil)
```

I am being given this error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant MotionlessAgitator):
  app/models/employee.rb:5:in `import'
  app/controllers/employees_controller.rb:65:in `import'
```

Have tried calling with/without the "::" and from within the controller. I'm still fairly new at this and not exactly sure how the load paths work though

Comment: In order to get your class loaded automatically, you should have it in app/models/motionless_agitator/employee_availability.rb file.

Comment: @santosh that's exactly what I wrote. Why do you duplicate it?

Comment: Just now your updates loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing underscores in directory and file names. In order to get your class loaded automatically, you should have it in `app/models/motionless_agitator/employee_availability.rb` file.